# Sample AlarmController application Service registeration in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-manifest, broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android and trying to implement the sample AlarmController application. Everything is fine but its Alarm Service is not working. I was wondering that do I need to register these services in the AndroidManifest.xml file as the other activities a are registered and if yes. How do I do that, I guess the alarm controller code is Available on Android's website therefore I am just putting the AndroidManifest.xml code of my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.AlarmController"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AlarmActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it as the "CommonsWare" said in the other answer there needs to be a service tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.AlarmController"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AlarmActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="AlarmService_service" />    

    </application>


</manifest>
```

So whatever service, reciever, activity and etc you are using, you need to register it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `<service>` element inside your `<application>` element, indicating the class that implements the service.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader) from one of my books demonstrating the use of a `Service`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/tree/master/demo) demonstrating [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), an open source component I wrote to simplify the use of `AlarmManager` when you want the alarms to wake up the phone.